# ASP.NET MVC 4: table for model's inner list

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a ViewModel that extends a well known base class in order to allow shared View to read common attributes. This is by design.

I also have pages that display details about lists of entities contained in the model. The following code provides an example:

```
public abstract class AbstractViewModel {
      public Exception lastError; //If not null triggers a big warning
}

public class Cat{
      [Display(...)]
      public string Name;
}

public class CatListViewModel: AbstractViewModel {
      public IEnumerable<Cat> cats;
}
```

Now my partial view needs to display a list of cats using common MVC ways

```
@model Org.Zighinetto.CatListViewModel

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Cats.Name) //Doesn't work!!
        </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Cats)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Unfortunately I can't use `DisplayNameFor` with a collection as argument

### The question is

Given the above data model, and given that I don't want to change model nature to `IEnumerable<Cat>` for design reasons...

How can I bind the display name, which is an attribute of the `Cat` class, to the `DisplayNameFor` method or any equivalent when the expression involves a collection especially when this collection is empty? Otherwise asked, how can I fix the above compilation error? What's the correct syntax for `DisplayNameFor` in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found by myself by luck.

Basically `Html.DisplayNameFor(Model => Model.Cats.FirstOrDefault().Name)` works because even if there are no cats the runtime reflects the type `Cat` correctly

Comment: @DavidTansey because djechelon can't, not right now, [have a look at this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/).

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you need to watch out in your code to prevent null exception.

**First**, you need to need to initialize you `Cats` collection so that when your code does not do so, for valid reason and it happens in reality, you are protected from having null exception. So you can write your model as such:

```
public class CatListViewModel: AbstractViewModel {
    public CatListViewModel() {
        Cats = new List<Cat>();
    }
    public IEnumerable<Cat> Cats;
}
```

So in your view if you do `Model.Cats.FirstOrDefault()` you won't get a null exception because `Cats` is null.

**Secondly**, now that you "can" have an empty collection (**not** null), because you are initializing it when an instance of your `CatListViewModel` is created, you still can run into null exception. That is because you are telling the compiler to give you a `NULL` if there is no item in the list - `Model.Cats.FirstOrDefault()`. So what you need to do is:

```
<th>
    @if (Model.Cats.Any()) {
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Cats.First().Name)
    }
</th>
```